# Differentiate between number and alphabet in grok filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have two log lines like this:

```
[2020-04-01][14:57:31]E: Step 8/13: Main workflow (Python) (8m:48s)
[2020-04-01][15:14:02]W: Cannot find Latest build with tag: 'ArtifactSizeBaseline' to calculate metric 'total artifacts size'.
```

and a matching string like this

```
%{DATE:EventDate}\]\[%{TIME:EventTime}\](\s+)?%{WORD:Loglevel}:(\s+)?%{DATA:Step}:(\s+)%{GREEDYDATA:EventMessage}
```

My output should look like this for statement one:

```
{'EventDate':'2020-04-01', 'EventTime':'14:57:31', 'LogLevel':'E', 'Step':'Step 8/13', 'EventMessage':'Main workflow (Python) (8m:48s)'}
```

Ideally, the second logline does not contain a step. So, the output should look like

```
{'EventDate':'2020-04-01', 'EventTime':'15:14:02', 'LogLevel':'W', 'Step':'', 'EventMessage':'Cannot find Latest build with tag: 'ArtifactSizeBaseline' to calculate metric 'total artifacts size'.'}
```

But what I get is this

```
{'EventDate':'2020-04-01', 'EventTime':'15:14:02', 'LogLevel':'W', 'Step':'Cannot find Latest build with tag: ', 'EventMessage':''ArtifactSizeBaseline' to calculate metric 'total artifacts size'.'}
```

Is there a way for the match string to differentiate between these two log lines?

Comment: You could make the field step optional like this: `%{DATE:EventDate}\]\[%{TIME:EventTime}\](\s+)?%{WORD:Loglevel}:(\s+)?(Step %{DATA:Step}:)?(\s+)%{GREEDYDATA:EventMessage}`. But this will change the value you're getting for Step: `Step 8/13 -> 8/13`

Comment: has my suggested regex solved your issue? If you feel satisfied, I would appreciate if you would accept my answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex matches both lines:

```
%{DATE:EventDate}\]\[%{TIME:EventTime}\](\s+)?%{WORD:Loglevel}:\s+((?=Step\s\b)%{DATA:Step}:)?\s?%{GREEDYDATA:EventMessage}
```

It uses a positive lookahead as well as the optional DATA-extraction if the word "Step" is found followed by a whitespace and a number.

Tested for both lines on this site:

https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

I hope I could help you.